# Does VisualSVN Server 3 support HTTP compression?

Tags: svn, http, compression, visualsvn-server

Does anyone know if version 3 of VisualSVN server supports HTTP compression? It was in 2.0 then dropped in 2.0.4 and I thought it was meant to be incorporated back into 3 but now can’t find any references (Visual SVN is very light on documentation).

Comment: Why do you need http compression? Do you need it to optimize overall performance (ie. speed to do an update) or reduce bandwidth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, VisualSVN Server doesn't support HTTP compression <s>and most likely will not support it in future because of memory leaks in mod_dav_svn/mod_deflate ([SVN-3084](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SVN-3084)).</s>

But Subversion deltas already self-compressed so there is no big benefit to use HTTP compression for Subversion traffic.

**UPDATE:** The ([SVN-3084](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SVN-3084)) issue has been fixed, so VisualSVN Server will support HTTP compression someday, but currently it doesn't. You may add the following lines to `%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\conf\httpd-custom.conf` if you really want HTTP compression in VisualSVN Server:

```
LoadModule deflate_module bin/mod_deflate.so

# Disable builtin Subversion compression
SVNCompressionLevel 0

# Enable HTTP compression
DeflateCompressionLevel 5
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
```

**IMPORTANT:** Make sure that you are using VisualSVN Server 3.5.7 or later, otherwise you may get excessive memory usage in some cases.

Comment: Is this answer true for SVN 1.9.5 and newer versions? I'm asking because it seems that [SVN-3084](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SVN-3084) has been recently resolved and the [fix was included in SVN 1.9.5 patch update](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SVN-3084?focusedCommentId=15705781&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-15705781).

Comment: @bahrep Thank you for reminding! I've updated my answer.